# Inject live data into a chartist Bar Chart - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, chartist.js

I am looking to update a bar charts data every 10 or so seconds without refreshing the entire page,

I use this method for pulling array data from a Laravel controller function,

```
function getChartData(){
  $.get( "tickets/chart/firstresponse", function( data ) {
    $( ".result" ).html( data );

  console.log(data);
  return data;

  });

  setTimeout(getChartData, 150000);

}

getChartData();
```

Below is a snippet of my chart, I need to be able to pull the data from the controller and place in seriesdata,

```
function barChart(){

var seriesdata = [['1','2','3','4','5']];

new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
  labels: ['8', '30', '60', '90', '180'],
  series: getChartData()
}
```

So you have the full picture here is what I have in my controller, currently only test data,

```
public function firstResponseChart(){

$array = [['1','2','3','4','5']];

return $array;

}
```

I can console.log(data) from the getChartData() function and it returns how I would expect it

[image]

I just need to data to be used in the series, once I have acomplished that I can then just set a timeout on the chart to reload every so often.

Answer (score 0):

I have got it working using the following, I don't know if its the best practice, but for someone who doesn't write javascript that often, I don't think its to bad.

My issue was passing the data from the function to another function, When I embedded the chart inside the function I used to get the data from the Laravel Controller it worked.

Then from within the child function, I called the timeout so it refreshes and pulls the data from the contoller.

```
function dataChart() {

    $.get("http://localhost:8000/tickets/chart/firstresponse", function(data) {
        $(".result").html(data);


        function barChart() {

            new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', {
                labels: ['8', '30', '60', '90', '180'],
                series: data
            }, {
                chartPadding: {
                    top: 20,
                    right: 0,
                    bottom: 30,
                    left: 0
                },
                axisY: {
                    onlyInteger: true
                },
                plugins: [
                    Chartist.plugins.ctAxisTitle({
                        axisX: {
                            axisTitle: 'Days',
                            axisClass: 'ct-axis-title',
                            offset: {
                                x: 0,
                                y: 50
                            },
                            textAnchor: 'middle'
                        },
                        axisY: {
                            axisTitle: 'Minutes',
                            axisClass: 'ct-axis-title',
                            offset: {
                                x: 0,
                                y: 0
                            },
                            textAnchor: 'middle',
                            flipTitle: false
                        }
                    })
                ]
            }).on('draw', function(data) {
                if (data.type === 'bar') {
                    data.element.attr({
                        style: 'stroke-width: 30px;stroke:skyblue;'
                    });
                }
            });

            setTimeout(dataChart, 10000);


        }


        barChart();
    })



}

dataChart();
```